# scale property of ALAssetRepresentation always return 1

Tags: ios, iphone, alasset

I'm trying to get original image from `ALAsset` and find that the `scale` property of `ALAssetRepresentation` always returns 1.0. So I wonder is there a situation that the property will return other value like 2.0 ?

```
ALAssetRepresentation *assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation] ;
CGImageRef imgRef = assetRepresentation.fullResolutionImage ;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgRef] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

After retina displays were introduced physical resolution was doubled but for API calls it was remained the same. So in some methods and functions (see `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` for example) was added additional argument 'scale'. I do not know why `[ALAssetRepresentation scale]` description is so poor

> Returns the representation's scale.

but you can look at `UIScreen.scale` description

> This value reflects the scale factor needed to convert from the
>   default logical coordinate space into the device coordinate space of
>   this screen. The default logical coordinate space is measured using
>   points. For standard-resolution displays, the scale factor is 1.0 and
>   one point equals one pixel. For Retina displays, the scale factor is
>   2.0 and one point is represented by four pixels.

I think `[ALAssetRepresentation scale]` should be 2.0 if you will run this code on device with retina display.

Comment: I'm sorry that I run my code in retina device but still get 1.0.

Comment: Maybe "vice versa"? Can you try it on non-retina device?